# HTML / CSS navbar dropdown in background?

Tags: html, css

Hello i have begun with a website with html, css etc. and am just busy at the navbar, the problem is it seems that the dropdwon navbar is behind the body content? does anyone know why, I had tried z-index without success?

Screenshot: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=162Xk8sNiF-mAfe9oWTLZyybSgQAtCyi-

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/atxkbjd3

thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="navbar">
    <h1 class="logo">Test</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#social" class="dropbtn">Social</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#forum">Forum</a>
...
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#game" class="dropbtn">Game</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#changelog">test 1</a>
...
                    </div>
                </li>
...
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
...
nav>ul>li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 70px;
    padding-top: 17px;
    position: relative;
}

nav>ul>li>a {
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
}

...

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
...
```

Comment: Add your code with working like jsfiddle

Comment: Hi @jamefane, when asking these kind of questions it's best to add a codepen or jsfiddle showing the actual issue. Especially because your screenshot results in a 404.

Comment: Your google drive link is not working for me maybe add the image directly into the post.

Comment: Google link is working now and i added a jsfiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `overflow` `hidden` for `header`

```
header {
    background: #EDEDED;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/atxkbjd3/2/

Comment: Thank god, thanks a lot, I've been on for a few hours xD

Answer (score 0):

Simply add some `z-index` value to your drop-down menu in Css.
This should let it show infront of the other elements instead of behind them.